# Фильтры с DI в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

В чем отличие `ServiceFilterAttribute` от `TypeFilterAttribute`? Ну кроме того что второй не надо регистрировать в контейнере. И где какой использовать?

Comment: [Similar to the TypeFilterAttribute in that both use constructor injection. Use TypeFilterAttribute instead if the filter is not itself a service.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.servicefilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ServiceFilterAttribute

Класс `ServiceFilterAttribute` извлекает экземпляр фильтра напрямую из DI.

**Особенности:**

- Необходимо регистрировать фильтры в `Startup` классе;
- За счет использования `ServiceProvider`, мы можем задавать жизненный
  цикл для экземпляра фильтра. Например,
  `services.AddSingleton<SomeFilter>();` позволит создать экземпляр фильтра один раз и использовать его на протяжении работы приложения. Это даст небольшой прирост в производительности.

### TypeFilterAttribute

Класс `TypeFilterAttribute` создает экземпляр фильтра с помощью фабрики `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ObjectFactory`.

**Особенности:**

- Не нужно регистрировать фильтры в `Startup` классе;
- Экземпляр фильтра создается каждый раз при запросе;
- Можно передавать кастомные параметры в конструктор фильтра с помощью свойства `Arguments`.

Например, вот такой фильтр:

```
public class AgeFilterAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public AgeFilterAttribute(int age, ILogger logger)
    {
    }
}
```

Можно использовать вот так:

```
public class AlcoController : Controller
{
    [TypeFilter(typeof(AgeFilterAttribute), Arguments = new object[]{ 18 })]
    public IActionResult Beer()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [TypeFilter(typeof(AgeFilterAttribute), Arguments = new object[]{ 21 })]
    public IActionResult Vodka()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Мораль:** если не нужны параметры в конструкторе, используй `ServiceFilterAttribute` с правильно указанным жизненным циклом при регистрации в `Startup` классе.

Comment: Нет смысла делать фильтр атрибутом, а потом подключать его через TypeFilter...

Comment: Заблуждение, вызванное нехваткой опыта (: